# Error installing service worker

Tags: angular

I have successfully published my Angular 2 using CLI Build on IIS, the app is working fine but in console I am getting this error

> ****Error installing service worker**DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.**